# How to convert map[string]interface{} to map[string]string

Tags: go, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a `map[string]interface{}` to `map[string]string` and whenever I try I get a panic:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    var doc interface{}
    js := `{ "id": "123", "links": { "self": "/app/123" } }`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &doc)
    jsonObj, _ := doc.(map[string]interface{})
    myFunc_convert(jsonObj)
}

func myFunc_convert(js map[string]interface{}) {
  links := js["links"].(map[string]string)
  links["hi"] = "foo"
}

func myFunc_noConvert(js map[string]interface{}) {
  links := js["links"]
  links["hi"] = "foo"
}
```

Gives me the following error if I call myFunc_convert:

```
interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not map[string]string
```

If I call myFunc_noConvert I get this error:

```
invalid operation: links["hi"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

I know ahead of time that links will be a `map[string]string` and **I need to be able to add items to it**. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

I thought about creating a new map of type `map[string]string`, then looping through everything in links and converting it to type string and putting it in the new map, but that seems clunky.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No. Those are two different types, and there is no direct conversion between them. But since you're unmarshalling JSON, you could just define a type and then you wouldn't have to deal with any conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var doc interface{}
    js := `{ "id": "123", "links": { "self": "/app/123" } }`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &doc); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    jsonObj, _ := doc.(map[string]interface{})
    links := myFunc(jsonObj)
    links["hi"] = "foo"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", links)
}

func myFunc(js map[string]interface{}) map[string]string {
    result := map[string]string{}
    links, ok := js["links"].(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return result
    }
    for k := range links {
        if v, ok := links[k].(string); ok {
            result[k] = v
        }
    }
    return result
}
```